# Hadoop API Jars Organization

Tags: java, maven, hadoop, hadoop-yarn, cloudera-cdh

I am a beginner Hadoop developer and to an extent have been map-reduce applications for about a few months but I am confused about how the maven dependencies and jar imports work. In order to write a full map-reduce program, what are the dependencies I need to include in my pom file. So far I am ashamed to say I have been just adding dependencies left and right until my imports no longer result in an error. I tried looking online but I could never get a solid answer. So far here is what I know

This is the repository I need to use:
Cloudera (what I need to use CDH5.3 Hadoop 2.5 with YARN)

And a whole list of artifacts: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop

Can someone please clear this up for me. I am developing on a CDH5.3 platform running Hadoop 2.50. What is the latest API I can use and what artifacts and dependencies do I need to include to cover all my bases. (ie. using distributed cache, the filesystem, the latest possible version of things like job (which should replace distributed cache)

Thanks so much